# Geolocation response country_name doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, country-codes

My geolocation responsove country_name is working in Chrome and Firefox, but isn't on Safari. How can I fix this?

Javascript:

```
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    if(response.country_code=='NL'||response.country_code=='US'){
        document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="NL">THE NL</div>
<div id="US">THE US</div>
```

CSS:

```
#NL { display:none;} 
#US { display:none;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P8j6n/185/)

Comment: Do you have some ad block plugin in safari?

Comment: No active ad blockers. However if I inspect the element, Safari gives the following error:  [Warning] [blocked] The page was not allowed to run insecure content from http://freegeoip.net/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle is working in latest Safari on High Sierra. I checked this in Chrome too, and it was not working because of Ad Blocking plugin, that blocks the request to http://freegeoip.net/json/

To overcome this problem, you could create a proxy on your backend (create simple script, that will do the GET request for you, so the client request will be just to the same same that its originating).

But the error you noted `The page was not allowed to run insecure content from freegeoip.net/json` is about something different - you are trying to do request to unsecure site (`http://` instead of `https://`).

Fortunately this service also runs on https, just add the `s` to the link and it should be working.

```
$.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    if(response.country_code=='NL'||response.country_code=='US'){
        document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: No problem, but as I noted, be aware that users with ad block will have similar problem. One posibility to overcome this would be doing the request to your backend that would do that request for you.